# Struggling with Python - How to return suite and card value?

Tags: python

I've been trying to do this Python assignemnt that I got but I have so far had no luck.

I have 2 files currently, one being playing cards.py which contains this:
mport random

```
# Deck of cards - first letter represents the face value and
# second letter represents the suit
deck = ['AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
        'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
        'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS',
        'AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC']

# Playing deck in use
playing_deck = []


# Function to determine whether there are any cards left in the
# deck of playing cards
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: True if the deck is empty, False otherwise
def is_empty_deck():

    # Check to see whether playing deck is empty
    return len(playing_deck) == 0


# Function to rebuild and shuffle the deck
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: Nothing is returned from the function.
def reset_deck():
    global playing_deck

    # Create new playing deck
    playing_deck = deck.copy()

    # Shuffle deck
    random.shuffle(playing_deck)


# Function to deal one card
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: A string (containing two characters) representing
# the card delt, i.e. '2H' meaning 2 of Hearts
def deal_one_card():

    # Check to see whether there are any cards left
    if is_empty_deck():

        # Rebuild and shuffle deck
        reset_deck()

    # Return a card (string of two characters)
    return playing_deck.pop(0)
```

In my next file I have

```
import playing_cards
import random


player_hand = []
dealers_hand = []



#Players Cards
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
player_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
player_hand.append(card)
print(player_hand)

#Dealer Cards
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
dealers_hand.append(card)
print(dealers_hand)
```

This returns the values like this:
['5H', '7D']
['4C', 'QD']

How do I go about splitting these value up into their suite and card value ?
E.g.: 5 of Hearts and 7 of Diamonds?

Been trying for a couple of hours but with no luck, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just return both of them: `return '5H', '7D'`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Do you want a function that takes `['5H', '7D'] ` as input and returns `['5 of Hearts', '7 of Diamonds']`? Or do you just need it to return something like `[('5', 'H'), ('7', 'D')]`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for your question, is that the card is the first character of the string and the suit is the second.  You could write `card[0]` for the number and `card[1]` for the suit.   This lets you make code like:

```
isFlush = len(set([card[1] for card in dealers_hand])) == 1`
```

It looks magical, so let's do it again, but with functions:

```
function suit(card):
   # return single character suit of card
   return card[1]

function rank(card):
   # return rank of card from 1 for ace to 13 for King
   return ' A23456789TJQK'.find(card)

function is_flush(hand):
   suits_in_hand = [suit(card) for card in dealers_hand]
   different_suits_in_hand = set(suits_in_hand)
   if len(different_suits_in_hand) == 1:
      is_flush = True
   else:
      is_flush = False
   return is_flush

# disclaimer, I've been in JavaScript all week so my syntax could be off.
```

Comment: You may want to add 1 in the `rank()` function if you really want to return 1 for an Ace, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you want to translate '5H' to '5 of Hearts'. That is most easily done by introducing a function that translates your card to a text string:

```
suits = {
    'C': 'Clubs',
    'D': 'Diamonds',
    'H': 'Hearts',
    'S': 'Spades'
}

values = {
    'A': 'Ace',
    'T': '10', # Or 'T': 'Ten', depending on preference
    'J': 'Jack',
    'Q': 'Queen',
    'K': 'King'
}

def card_to_string(card):
    value = card[0]
    suit = card[1]    
    value_string = values[value] if values.has_key(value) else value
    suit_string = suits[suit]
    return "{} of {}".format(value_string, suit_string)
```

Then, to generate a hand, you need a function to compose the cards, e.g. like:

```
def hand_to_string(hand):
    hand_string = card_to_string(hand[0])
    for card in hand[1:-1]:
        hand_string += ", {}".format(card_to_string(card))
    if (hand[0] != hand[-1]):
        hand_string += " and {}".format(card_to_string(hand[-1]))
    return hand_string
```

Comment: How would I make a function to compose the cards?

Comment: I have added a function printing a hand to the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that procedure always returns only this type of strings, spit this is very simple:

```
>>> c,d='5D'
>>> c
'5'
>>> d
'D'
```